# Get Division in the html tag with value of the elementa

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing

HI i need that the image tag should be generated in the division for number of times it receives the object. But it doesn't work. Can anyone please help me with same. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
<div id="validation" class="subcontent" >

<script type="text/javascript">

  Parse.initialize("@@@@", "@@@@");
  //var description1 = document.getElementById("news").value;
  var uid1 = document.getElementById("uid").value;
  var interior= Parse.Object.extend("Interior");
  var query = new Parse.Query(interior); 
  query.equalTo("user_id", uid1);
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");

  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  // This does not require a network access.  
    var Imageurl = results[i].get("image_url");
    var Imageur2 = results[i].get("image_title");
    var elemen = Imageurl;
    var elemen1 = Imageur2;
    var content = "<img src='+elemen+' />"; 
  // Insert using this:
  document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = content;
   }
 },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: the way it works on stackoverflow.com is that you accept and upvote an answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not stating which libraries you are using i assume you aren't using any, so here is a loop which would actually append the images to your element:

(I'm assuming `results` is a normal object)

```
var imageUrl,
    imageUr2,
    content = '';

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    imageUrl  = results[i].image_url;
    imageUr2 = results[i].image_title;

    content += '<img src="'+elemen+'" />'; 
}
document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = content;
```

This will correctly append all the images in your result object to your `validation` DOM-element. Your error was that you didn't properly concatenate the strings and you ended up with `<img src="+elemen+" />` instead of the proper path.

Also you always overwrote your content, instead of concatenating everything first, before appending it to the DOM.